# Problemas ao abrir um Select One Menu dentro de um p:dialog

Tags: jsf, aplicação-web, java-ee, xhtml

Eu possuo um `select one menu` dentro um `p:dialog`, consigo ver que ele carrega os dados, mas não abre, não faz o drop down, fora do `p:dialog` ele funciona normalmente.

Pesquisei sobre mas não achei nenhum resultado.

Meu XHTML:

```html
<p:dialog appendTo="@(body)"  header="Meu perfil" responsive="true" widgetVar="perfilModal" height="400" width="1000" resizable="false" >
   <h:form id="formularioAlterar">
      <p:outputPanel id="painelAlterar">
         <h:message for="msgValidador" />
         <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
            <div class="ui-g-12">
               <p:outputLabel value="Selecione sua cidade:*" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-12">
               <p:selectOneMenu filter="true" id="cidade" value="#{funcionarioMB.funcionario.idCidade}" required="true" requiredMessage="Necessário informar uma cidade" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                  <f:selectItems value="#{funcionarioMB.cidades}" var="cidade" itemValue="#{cidade.idCidade}" itemLabel="#{cidade.nomeCidade} - #{cidade.sigla}" />
               </p:selectOneMenu>
               <p:message for="cidade" />
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="Salvar" styleClass="btn btn-success btn-block" action="#{funcionarioMB.AlterarPerfil()}" oncomplete="PF('mensagem').show()"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" id="Cancelar" styleClass="btn btn-danger btn-block" oncomplete="PF('perfilModal').hide()"></p:commandButton>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
         </div>
      </p:outputPanel>
   </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Observação, percebi que ele abre atrás do p:dialog

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido com

`appendTo="@this"` dentro do Select One Menu